# Java library to detect whether picture is selfie or not

Tags: android, open-source, java, image-recognition, facial-recognition

We develop an Android [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.free.nrw.commons) that allows people to upload pictures to Wikimedia Commons.
PROBLEM: Often some funny fellows upload their own selfies, rather than pictures with educational value.

So, I would like the Android app to recognize whether a picture is a selfie or not.

Requirements:

- 100% pure Java library
- Compatible with GNU-GPLv3
- Less than 1MB

A library that uses facial recognition and gives the position/size of faces in the picture is also OK, I would consider the image a selfie if any face takes more than 10% of the image's area.

Comment: Is this a good idea? I can imagine pictures of public figures being useful, plus you need some sort of moderation in place other than just "not-selfie".

Comment: @CamiloMartin: I simplified because it is not really the point of the question, but you are right, it is only a kind of warning/flagging, and it does not prevent users from uploading.

Comment: Using machine learning I developed some Tensorflow/Keras code that can tell whether a picture is a selfie or not with 85% accuracy: https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/selfie-or-not Next it needs 1) More data samples to improve reliability 2) To be made into a Java library of acceptable size.